# Crouton install

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, vlc

I run Ubuntu 12.04 which is recently updated. What media programs can I install? I have tried VLC but .deb files mostly tell me "corrupt". I run on a HP Chromebook 14.

Answer (score 0):

You could install VLC from your Ubuntu Software Center, just search for VLC and it will be there.
[image]

Or from your terminal with `sudo apt-get install vlc`

If you met any problem during the installation, you could try to run `sudo apt-get install -f` to correct dependency issues. If it's still not working, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/564921/edit) your question and append the error message, it will be helpful for debugging.

If you want to know what else you could choose, please search "Media Player" in your software center, there are a plenty of them.